# Como redimensionar gráficos no IPython Notebook sem perda da qualidade?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython-notebook

No IPython Notebook eu produzo gráficos com (por exemplo):

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
plot(x, y)
```

Quando posiciono o cursor sobre o gráfico gerado, aparece no canto inferior direito a ferramenta para redimensionar o gráfico. Porém, quando eu redimensiono o mesmo fica "pixelado":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu posso informar `figure(figsize=(12,8))` antes de plotar o gráfico mas não me parece a solução mais eficiente (precisa ser especificado antes de cada gráfico). Existe alguma forma de redimensionar gráficos no Notebook de forma interativa e sem perda de qualidade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No lugar de produzir gráficos em PNG (formato de imagem bitmap), você pode configurar o IPython Notebook para produzir gráficos em SVG (formato vetorial), que não perde a definição.

Você pode mudar o formato padrão dos gráficos, adicione o seguinte ao início de seu arquivo notebook (funciona a partir do IPython 1.0):

```py
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='svg'
```

Usando SVG você não terá mais a ferramenta de redimensionar gráfico, mas poderá usar o zoom do seu navegador para ver o gráfico mais de perto.

### Tamanho padrão das figuras

Se preferir continuar usando PNG, você definir o tamanho padrão para as figuras:

```py
%config InlineBackend.rc={'figure.figsize': (12, 8)}
```

ou

```py
import pylab
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 8.0)
```

### Retina

Ainda usando PNG, você pode usar o *backend* `retina`, que produz imagens com 4 vezes a resolução:

```py
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'
```

Você pode combinar essa solução com a anterior.

Comment: Será que vale um feature request pra não ter que ficar usando o zoom do navegador? Ou é particularidade do svg mesmo?

Comment: Há uma implementação, mas não funciona bem. Veja isso: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1832/

Comment: Foi a melhor solução até agora, resolve o problema por enquanto. Aceitando.